# ObjectBox Flutter: Clear all the tables on logout

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I am using [ObjectBox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox) for the database and I have created a couple of tables. Now I need to clear all the tables (like truncate to start primary id from 1 again) like Clean the Database.

I didn't found any method or way to clear the database.

I thought to use **removeAll** for all the tables, but I think it's not the proper way.

Please do let me know if is there any other way to do it.

Thanks,
Pratik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do seems like you want to start the database from scratch. In that case, you can delete the database directory before initializing `Store()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you can copy/paste and change your database name.

```
  static void removeAllData() async {
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Directory(dir.path + '/your_db').delete().then((FileSystemEntity value) => print("DB Deleted: ${value.existsSync()}"));
  }
```